# asp.net core identity. insert logged in user ID to a table as FK

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

How can I insert current user into the Invite table ask FK?
Invite Model have been scaffolded

Models

```
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]    //ICollection<Invite> in User 
        [Display(Name = "Users")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }

=================

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("GameID")] 
        public int? GameID { get; set; }
        public Game Game { get; set; }
        public string GameTag { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Invite> Invite { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your `Invite` model does not specify the ForeingnKey as a property,you just get the current user and add to the `Invite` instance:

```
public class InvitesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public InvitesController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Invite invite)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            invite.User = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User); //add this...
            _context.Add(invite);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(invite);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Invite
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]    //ICollection<Invite> in User 
    [Display(Name = "Users")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GameID")]
    public int? GameID { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    public string GameTag { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Invite> Invite { get; set; }
}
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```